# Please recommend a smart, elegant way to write these repetitive 'if' statements

Tags: php, if-statement, formatting

I just know I'm doing this in a really bad way:

```
<?php } elseif ( is_single()) { 

    $url = wp_get_referer();
    $path_parts = pathinfo($url);
    $mycat = $path_parts['filename'];

    if ( $mycat == "animation"  ) {
        $_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat;?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
<?php } elseif ($mycat == "direction"){     
        $_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat;?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
<?php } elseif ($mycat == "grading"){   
        $_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat;?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
<?php } elseif ($mycat == "online"){    
        $_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat;?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
<?php } elseif ($mycat == "showcase"){  
        $_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat;?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
<?php } elseif ($mycat == "showreel"){  
        $_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat;?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
<?php } elseif ($mycat == "vfx"){   
        $_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat;?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
<?php }else{ ?><a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a><?php };?>

<?php } //end if is_single ?>
```

It works. But it's messy and repetitive. I tried going this route:

```
<?php if ($mycat == "animation" || "direction" || "grading"){
```

But it didn't work at all.

Comment: Your code is insecure.  Please learn about Cross-Site Scripting vulnerabilities.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: @kemp: `<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>` just echoes the session variable as is.

Comment: @Bill: by insecure you mean $_SESSION can't be trusted?

Comment: @kemp - the session is being set based on parts from the URL of the request, so you could put anything (e.g. JavaScript) into the URL and have it saved to the session... and in turn that would be echoed directly to the page

Comment: @John: I can't see the code that sets that variable, outside of the controlled ifs

Comment: @kemp - you are correct, I didn't even notice that (I had also voted up David's answer because I thought all branches were identical!). I guess this also means this code is *not* subject to XSS vulnerabilities as it stands written here.

Comment: It's the source of the data you put into $_SESSION that you can't trust.  You're getting the HTTP referer via the wordpress function `wp_get_referer()`.  But a client can send anything it wants to send as the referer.  It's as simple as `wget --referer=anything`.  Then you use that referer content sent by the client, save it in your $_SESSION, and subsequently echo it directly in your HTML output without escaping.  So the referer could contain javascript.

Comment: @Bill: that piece of code only sets the session variable if the input value matches any of the given strings, otherwise it uses the elsewhere defined value: the fallback condition doesn't assign a value.

Comment: @kemp: Aha, I see.  Sorry for the false alarm.  Still, it's worthwhile to be mindful of XSS vulnerabilties.

Answer (score 7):

Create an array holding the values, then test if the value of `$mycat` exists in the array. Also, you're echoing the link whatever `$mycat` is, so the else statement can be completely dropped and the if structure further simplified to just the following:

```
$categories = array(
    'animation', 
    'direction', 
    'grading', 
    'online', 
    'showcase', 
    'showreel', 
    'vfx'
);

if (in_array($mycat, $categories)) {
    $_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat;
}

?>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
```

And like others have said, remember to escape your output.

Comment: @kemp: +1 back to you anyway ;)

Comment: Actually, if you look at his final else statement, you can see that it captures *everything* regardless of if it's in the array or not. So as insecure as this is - escaping anyone? - you can simplify it to this:

<a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>

Comment: @CaseySoftware: thanks, I knew there was something I missed. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$cats = array(
    'animation',
    'direction',
    'grading',
    'online',
    'showcase',
    'showreel'
    'vfx',
);
if ( in_array($mycat, $cats) ) :
    $_SESSION['theCategory'] = $mycat; ?>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $mycat;?>"><?php echo $mycat;?></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I love how we're both getting the same number of upvotes and how they're coming in simultaneously.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but perhaps for the duplicated code (both A elements are identical)...  Not a big deal (especially since you avoid the additional array lookup), but I could understand why someone MIGHT consider that "not great"...

Answer (score 4):

And using the `switch` statement:

```
switch($mycat) {
    case 'animation':
    case 'direction':
    case 'grading':
    case 'online':
    case 'showcase':
    case 'showreel':
    case 'vfx':
        $_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat; 
    default:
        ?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
        <?php
}
```

Note the fall-through after the case statements.  You could either do that, or:

```
switch($mycat) {
    case 'animation':
    case 'direction':
    case 'grading':
    case 'online':
    case 'showcase':
    case 'showreel':
    case 'vfx':
        $_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat; 
}
?>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
<?php
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you even need a conditional here. You're not changing anything inside each conditional possibility.

```
$_SESSION["theCategory"] = $mycat;
<a href="<?php bloginfo('home')?>/category/<?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["theCategory"];?></a>
```

Comment: I guess the conditional is there as a white list

Comment: Thanks @Fosco. I had that thought too @kemp, but the 'else' statement at the end which basically prints the same href regardless of a match or not led me to a state of relative confusion :) A whitelist using in_array() is definitely appropriate here, but the bigger question is what does he want to do when no match is found?

Answer (score 1):

Use the in_array() function to write you condition:

```
<?php if (in_array($mycat, array("animation", "direction", "grading")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Path 1:

```
<?php if ($mycat == "animation" || $mycat == "direction" || $mycat == "grading"){
```

Path 2:

```
<?php if (in_array($mycat,array("animation","direction","grading"))) {
```